# Paths on DigitalOcean with Flask

Tags: python, path, flask

I have a Flask application on DigitalOcean that creates a `file(shapefile)`, and later on reads it again. How to write the paths of that file, to make sure it can be read later again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use paths relative to your application's root.
In Flask the application object ( `app` ) has a `.root_path` attribute you can use to create absolute paths to your files. Like:

```
with open(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'shapefiles', file_name), 'w') as f:
    f.write(....)
```

and later the reverse

```
with open(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'shapefiles', file_name), 'r') as f:
    data = f.read(....)
```